# /etc/init.d/rc: 317: sed: Permission Denied Ubuntu 9.04

Tags: ubuntu-9.04

I recently added NFS to my Ubuntu server and edited /etc/fstab to mount the network file system.  After a reboot I am not getting the following error several times on the console and it will not boot:

```
/etc/init.d/rc: 317: sed: Permission Denied
```

Any advice?  I have commented out the lines that I added to /etc/fstab and the issue still persists.

Thank You,

Comment: What appears in the few lines around line 317 of `/etc/init.d/rc`? On my Ubuntu 9.04 system, `sed` isn't used in that file.

Answer (score 0):

Could you open /etc/init.d/rc and find line 317 and post the whole sed command? I run Debian and just checked my rc file and do not have that command in there. I am going to guess however, that whatever file or possibly one of the folders the file is contained in has a permission problem prevent sed from executing its task.